# Using RANK with COUNT(DISTINCT) aggregation at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a subquery that joins my customers and transactions table, aliased as `jq`. I want to create a ranking of each customer's purchases (transactions) by order timestamp (`order_ts`). So I did,

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       order_id, 
       order_ts, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_ts ASC) AS purchase_rank, 
       amount 
FROM jq GROUP BY customer_id 
        ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Alongside with the `purchase_rank` column, I also want to know how many total purchases the customer have done. So this becomes:

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       order_id, 
       order_ts, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_ts ASC) AS purchase_rank, 
       // total purchases of this customer, counted by order_id
       amount 
FROM jq GROUP BY customer_id 
        ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Some `order_id`s are duplicated, so I want to count distinctly. How do I do this in MS SQL Server and Postgres without joining to a subquery?

Comment: are you using `SQL Server` or `postgresql` ?

Comment: It would be great if you can give some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Theoretically your query  should not work because `order_id`, and `order_ts `are not specified in the GROUP BY clause. Also what is `order_ts`? Is it not same for repeated `order_id`?

Comment: @Squirrel I want to know if it's possible on both.

Answer (score 1):

### Microsoft SQL Server

```
SELECT  customer_id,
    order_id,
    order_ts,
    purchase_rank,
    MAX(cnt) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) AS purchase_cnt,
    amount
FROM
(
    SELECT customer_id, 
           order_id, 
           order_ts, 
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_ts ASC) AS purchase_rank, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_id ASC) AS cnt, 
           amount 
    FROM jq 
    -- GROUP BY customer_id 
) AS D  
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Sorry, I am not familiar with `postgresql`.